# Joining multiple tables to get NOT EQUAL values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying for 3 days to solve this problem - now I need you guys :-)

I need to join 3 tables:

```
table data        table user           table collection
data_id | colors  user_id | user_name  collection_id | user_id | data_id
----------------  -------------------  ---------------------------------
   1    | blue       1    | Brian            1       |    1    |    1
   2    | red        2    | Jason            2       |    2    |    3
   3    | green      3    | Marie            3       |    1    |    3
   4    | yellow                             4       |    3    |    2
```

The outputs are user specific. That means Brian don't want to see blue and green, Jason don't want to see green and Marie don't want to see red.
That should give the following outputs:

```
for Brian           for Jason             for Marie
id | colors         id | colors           id | colors
-----------         -----------           -----------
2  | red            1  | blue             1  | blue
4  | yellow         2  | red              3  | green
                    4  | yellow           4  | yellow
```

Here is my best attempt (for now) how to solve this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    data d
        INNER JOIN
    user u ON u.user_id = d.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    collection c ON c.data_id = d.data_id
WHERE
    c.user_id <> '1' OR c.collection_id IS NULL
```

The result is that Brian's selections will getting sorted out - that's good! But because Jason don't want to see green either it's still selected for Brian.
Pretty confusing!

I hope i could write it more or less understandable =)

All help and hints are really appreciated!

cheers

**EDIT:** this solution is extended and got shorter by this solution: [replace the id with the username from an other table in a CROSS JOIN in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122561/replace-the-id-with-the-username-from-an-other-table-in-a-cross-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be using a  cross join and   not in table_collection

```
select user.id, user.name, data.data_id, data.data
from user 
cross join data
where (  user.user_id, data.data_id) not in ( 
   select user_id, data_id 
   from table_collection
)
```

Comment: Thats it! I only added after the where clause AND a.id = 1 and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot :-))

Comment: @scaisEdge: The alias names are just horrible. They make even this simple query a bit hard to read.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   .  correct  (in this case the tablename are short) .. answer updated avoiding aliases

Comment: You guys are right. I edited the alias names for a (hopeful) better reading.

Comment: In the data table is an extra column named "addedby" which inherits the user_id from the user table. It's the name who added this entry into the database out of the html form. Is it possible to extend your script to show who added this entry?

Comment: Yes is possibile but seems a new question .. and you should also provided a valid data sample and the expected  result  .. (any could also try yuorself)

Comment: Thank you for your help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether I the understood what you want but can you try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM data d
INNER JOIN user u ON 1=1
WHERE (u.id, d.id) NOT IN (SELECT user_id, data_id FROM collection)
```

Comment: @fhossfel: `INNER JOIN user u ON 1=1`? That's a cross join, so you should not make it look like an inner join, but write `CROSS JOIN user`.

Comment: Er, by the way, is that you Felix?

Comment: Yes, it is :-)

I am not sure what whether MySQL supports the CROSS JOIN syntax. The on 1=1 always seems more portable to me.

Comment: @fhossfel: Well, yes, MySQL is quite special sometimes (for instance you can write `INNER JOIN` and omit the `ON` clause). But it supports `CROSS JOIN`. So far the only DBMS I know of to support `INNER JOIN` but not `CROSS JOIN` is MS Access - but well, that's MS Access ;-) Nice to see we are sharing the same hobby, by the way :-)